# Runtime upgrade for `ParachainSystem::HostConfiguration`

Tags: runtime-upgrade, try-runtime

When testing my runtime upgrade from polkadot_v1.0.0 to 1.5.0 with try-runtime I get this error from `try-runtime`

> [2024-02-06T14:50:51Z ERROR runtime::executive] - 0. error: Failed to decode storage item `ParachainSystem::HostConfiguration`

Enabling debug info reveals the offending key `0x45323df7cc47150b3930e2666b0aa313c522231880238a0c56021b8744a00743` also known as `parachainSystem.hostConfiguration()`

Why does try-runtime think this type is `ParachainSystem::HostConfiguration`, this type is not even included in my build? In polkadot js the type is `PolkadotPrimitivesV5AbridgedHostConfiguration` before the upgrade and `v6` after.

When I delete the storage key in the migration the error disappears but will this have any negative side effects?

Comment: I observe the same when upgrading from Polkadot-sdk 1.0.0 to 1.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is "expected". When async backing was merged, the `HostConfiguration` type changed. The `AbridgedHostConfiguration` is, as the name suggests, an abridged version of the `HostConfiguration`. Basically it only includes the elements that are relevant for the parachain side. There was no migration added for this storage entry, because this storage entry is overridden by the `set_validation_data` inherent in each block. So, you can ignore this error.

Comment: Yep. The error should go away on its own after the next runtime upgrade, should open another issue if it doesn't.

Comment: We start to get into the mindset, if there is an error in try-runtime we should fix it not ignore it, so if this kind of false positives are common it is problematic for this work flow.

Comment: Yeah it sucks. This should be a one-off occurrence we couldn't avoid due to how the HostConfig stuff works. In the future should not happen again.